# Angular-cli serve watch not work under vagrant windows host

Tags: angular, vagrant, angular-cli

I have windows 10 host and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS under vagrant box. Shared folder with symlink permissions

```
config.vm.synced_folder "project_folder", "/home/vagrant/ngbox_project", type: "smb", mount_options: ["vers=3.02","mfsymlinks"]
```

Installed npm, angular-cli

```
npm 4.0.5

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
node: 4.7.0
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 2.4.1
@angular/compiler: 2.4.1
@angular/core: 2.4.1
@angular/forms: 2.4.1
@angular/http: 2.4.1
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.1
@angular/router: 3.4.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.1
```

Everything worked fine axcept ng serve not watch file changed at windows (via shared folder). If changes make at Ubuntu serve watch work. Соответственно Also not work build --watch eth

When i used webpack-dev-server (angular2 + webpack) installed manually not from ng-cli - watch work normally in both systems

trying `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` it doesn't help me.

P.S. I tryed to reinstall npm, ng-cli with cache remove. Shared folder path has not spaces.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Rsync only allows one-way synchronization (see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3062). So it is no good for working with angular-cli. Pardon me. Below you find a solution that should work.

### Working Solution

Use the vagrant plugin [**fsnotify**](https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify). It watches for changes on your host and repeats them on the guest.

### Not working solution

- **Rsync type** for shared folders in vagrant

  - only one-way-synchronization
- **vagrant-sshfs** plugin

  - mounting doesn't work at all (for me)